# jquery utter confusion with codekit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codekit

I'm following Ray Villalobos's advanced web development with bootstrap 3 on Lynda.com and have followed the course to the letter. I've got to combining and minifying Javascript files with Codekit and its showing me 100's of errors which I have absolutely no clue about.Things like this

> one of hundreds of errors:

if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
'module' is not defined. — column 47

> Is it perhaps because I've downloaded the 2.1.1 jquery rather than the 2.0.0 version shown on the tutorial? Can someone please help - its so frustrating! I mean I could go through and fix most of the "expecting == and got =" sort of stuff but I just have no idea why I'm getting these errors and clearly theres something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem could be, but I can't really answer this with more info. Do you have this published somewhere? I think with CodeKit you have to make sure you load the files in the right order. I know that CodeKit upgraded to version 2 since I recorded this, so that may be an issue. You may also want to try PrePros. I recorded a video on how to work with that here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XBb65yMMSg